# Home Page without Redirect

Tags: 2010, navigation

I want to be able to have users navigate to my site without being redirected to the aspx page representing the "Home Page".

Right now my home page is set to `Home.aspx` so when a user requests `http://blogs.mycompanysite.com/myblog/` they get redirected to `http://blogs.mycompanysite.com/myblog/Home.aspx`.

Effectively, I would like to set my home page to `/`. When the user requests `http://blogs.mycompanysite.com/myblog/` the actual file served would be `Home.aspx` but the url would still be `http://blogs.mycompanysite.com/myblog/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a URL rewrite rule.

[@Waldek Mastykarz](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/751/waldek-mastykarz) has a pretty nice blog post about this:

[From /Press-Releases/Pages/Press-Release.aspx to /Press-Releases/Press-Release – make friendly URL’s for your SharePoint site in 4 steps with IIS7 URL Rewrite module](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/friendly-urls-sharepoint-site-4-steps-iis7-url-rewrite-module/)

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on the Publishing features in the site (assuming your running Enterprise) you'll get a link in Site Settings called Welcome Page.  Here you can set Home.aspx as your default home page and when users enter `http://blogs.mycompanysite.com/myblog/` they'll be sent to `http://blogs.mycompanysite.com/myblog/Home.aspx` automatically.

Or am I missing something with what you're asking?

Comment: this is what it is currently doing. I don't want the user "sent" to Home.aspx, I want SharePoint to serve Home.aspx under the root `/` url. I have made corresponding edits to the question. Thanks.